# Multi Threading app and OpenCV in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, opencv

Basically I need to build an app where the main process does some operation based on the values of some global variables, and the secondary thread update this global variables (say each 100ms)

What library do you suggest to work with opencv, c++ and multithreading? (windows)

I have heard there are

- OpenMP
- Boost
- Intel TBB

Which one do you suggest for this simple multi thread application?

Comment: The question is too vague to receive a meaningful answer. Also, it would be good to show that you tried something before asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ supports threads since its newest standard. I would consider using `std::thread` from the standard library, if C++11 is an option for you. You can find the documentation for example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

The syntax is in my opinion very simple and easy to read (check out a few examples: [mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), [future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future), etc).

Comment: While the new standard is solid and exciting, one should not forget that usually there is a time gap measured in many years until the compilers offer full support for it. Especially in the embedded world.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP you can use for threads. You have OpenCV for computer vision.
Go with OpenMP. [Here's](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/) the documentation.
Hope it helps.:)

Comment: which is the OpenMP command to run a function as a separate Thread in parallel ?

Comment: you use the #pragma keyword to make and use threads. Its all given in the link I have provided and its easy to learn too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest boost libraries since it has large community and you will find all possible solutions and examples codes. Variable passing is easier than ever in Boost Threads. However, c++11 has similar thread functionality as boost but you need to check availability of c++ 11. So if you have already installed boost for other functionality, go with boost. Else c++ thread is your way out.